# Not able to find out the version of a module

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, version

I have imported **norm** as:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
```

I want to find out the version using:

```
print(scipy.__version__)
```

but it is raising an error called:

```
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

if i am using this:

```
print(norm.__version__)
```

but it is raising another error called:

```
AttributeError: 'norm_gen' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The line `from scipy.stats import norm` doesn't make the name `scipy` available in  your current namespace. To use `scipy.__version__`, you must first `import scipy`.

```
In [57]: import scipy                                                                                    

In [58]: print(scipy.__version__)                                                                        
1.4.1
```

Comment: Is there any way to find a version of **scipy** or **norm**  if i use `from scipy.stats import norm' only ?

Comment: No.  The version is only available in the top-level namespace `scipy`.